# Query regarding tar

Tags: unix, gzip, tar

I am doing tar of multiple files using absolute paths and sending the tar files to another server. While doing untar at target location my tar command is failing as it is not able to find the files.

Command which i used to tar and zip
tar -cf - list_of_file_names | gzip > output_file.tar.gz

and
Command to unzip and untar
gzip -dc output_file.tar.gz | tar -xf -

Is there any way possible to untar those files without getting any error ?

Comment: Can you paste the errors you get?  (Or at least the first few.)

Comment: tar:old username(changed from original): Permission denied          tar: cannot open "Path of original file" No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Why I see this, I'm usually trying to untar into a directory which I don't have write permissions for.

BTW, a more compact version of your commands:

```
tar czf output_file.tgz list_of_file_names

tar xzf output_file.tgz
```